# No bijection between quadratic forms and symmetric bilinear forms when the field is of characteristic 2

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space over $k$, a field of characteristic $2$, I wonder how to show that in general there is *no bijection* between quadratic forms and symmetric bilinear forms.

I understand that since in this case $2$ is not invertible, the canonical correspondence fails, but why couldn't there be any bijection between those two sets in general?

Comment: How to you deal with $b(x,y) = x_1y_2+x_2y_1$ with gives the same quadratic form as $b(x,y)=0$. For binary forms the $b$ and $q$ form two vector spaces of dimension 3 $\{\pmatrix{a & c\\ c& d}\}$ and $\{\pmatrix{a & c\\ 0 & d}\}$

Comment: If the vector space is infinite-dimensional, surely the cardinalities are the same, so there is a bijection.

Comment: So you need to be clear what you mean by "in general there is no bijection". If you mean "there is never a bijection" then (why not just say that, and) that isn't true, but if you mean "it is not the case that there is always a bijection", then you can just give an exampoke where there is no bijection

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Sorry for my ambiguity. What is an example with different cardinalities?

Comment: @reuns Sorry I don't get what you mean. What is q in your example? btw, I think $b(x,y) = x_1y_2+x_2y_1$ is not zero since if $x=(1,0), y=(0,1)$, then it's not zero

Comment: $b$ is the bilinear form and $q$ is the quadratic form. The canonical map sends $b(x,y)=x_1y_2+x_2y_1$ to the $q(x)=b(x,x)=0$ quadratic form. Do you understand my answer ?

Comment: allo ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In characteristic $2$ there is essentially the non-canonical (vector space) isomorphism from $n$-ary symmetric bilinear forms to $n$-ary quadratic forms $$\sum_{i,j} C_{ij} x_i y_j \mapsto \sum_{i \le j} C_{ij} x_i x_j \qquad (C_{ij} = C_{ji})$$
while the canonical map $\sum_{i,j} C_{ij} x_i y_j \mapsto \sum_{i, j} C_{ij} x_i x_j= \sum_i C_{ii} x_i^2$ is non-surjective nor injective (in characteristic not $2$ the canonical map is an isomorphism of $M_n(k)$ modules).

Comment: Sorry for my late response, it took me quite a while to figure it out.